# Print dropdown selected value using insertUI and removeUI in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to print the selected value from the dropdown which can be achieved with simple code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "test",
      label = "Test",
      choices = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"),
      selected = NULL),
    uiOutput("text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    req(input$test)
    
    input$test
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I am trying to do the same behavior but using the insertUI and removeUI functions from shiny. Like it will remove the previous selected value and will insert the new value.

Is there any way that this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dropdown", "Select a value:", choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
  div(id = "ui_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$dropdown, {
    # Insert a new UI element
    insertUI(
      selector = "#ui_output",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = div(
        class = "new_element",
        verbatimTextOutput("selected_value")
      )
    )
  })
  
  # Print the selected value in the new UI element
  output$selected_value <- renderText({
    input$dropdown
  })
  
  # Remove the UI element when the "Remove" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$remove_button, {
    removeUI(selector = ".new_element")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```